# Regular expression for matching sender SMTP address

Tags: regex, powershell, email

I have a working regular expression in PowerShell that can grab all SMTP addresses from an email header in an Outlook file (*.msg).

```
From: <Him him@hotmail.com>
To: Me <me@gmail.com>
CC: Somebody <someone@outlook.com>
Subject: Re: Testing RegEX
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 13:19:15 +0000
```

Below working code getting all headers

```
$header = Get-Content c:\work\headers.txt
$regex  = ‘\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b’
(Select-String -InputObject $header -Pattern $regex -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Using this regular expression I will get **him@hotmail.com me@gmail.com someone@outlook.com**.

But I only need **him@hotmail.com**, the SMTP address present in the *From:* line.

Also sometimes there are long SMTP routing addresses found in the header which I would like to exclude. Example *56DC1F3F67BF7844921154175A149C7C0522660A@mymailserver.subdomain.company.com*.
So I tried to exclude those with regular expression too, but when try to set the max length of SMTP address to 50:

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b){0,50}
```

It does not work, so obviously some syntax error.
Any tip you can give me?

Comment: What you're calling "routing addresses" are message IDs which usually appear in the `Message-Id` and `References` headers. They have nothing to do with mail routing. Also, please avoid using typographic quotes in code. They'll work most of the time, but in some cases they'll cause problems.

Comment: Frankly I'm more interested in how you got the headers out of the .msg file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the address from the `From:` header line you should match just that:

```
$regex = '(?<=^From: .*?)\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'
(Get-Content 'c:\work\headers.txt') -match $regex | ForEach-Object {
    $matches[0]
}
```

`(?<=^From: .*?)` is a positive lookbehind assertion, meaning it's used in the pattern matching, but not included in the returned result.

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar. When I use that regex it returns output, but it is the whole header in 1 line.`code` Select-String -InputObject $headertest -Pattern $regex1

From: <Him him@hotmail.com> To: Me <me@gmail.com> CC: Somebody <someone@outlook.com> Subject: Re: Testing RegEX Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 13:19:15 +0000`code`

Comment: Do you see a `Select-String` anywhere in my answer? The code I posted does *exactly* what you were asking. Please DO NOT get creative before you actually got things working.